# INSERT rows into SQL Server by looping through a column with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a very basic table:

| DAY_ID | Value | Inserts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 0 |

I want to be able to "loop" through the `Inserts` column, and add that many # of rows.

For each added row, I want `DAY_ID` to be decreased by 1 and `Value` to remain the same, `Inserts` column is irrelevant we can set to 0.

So 2 new rows should be added from `DAY_ID = 5` and `Value = 8`, and 1 new row with `DAY_ID = 2` and `Value = 4`. The final output of the new rows would be:

| DAY_ID | Value | Inserts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (5-1) | 8 | 0 |
| (5-2) | 8 | 0 |
| (2-1) | 4 | 0 |

I haven't tried much in SQL Server, I was able to create a solution in R and Python using arrays, but I'm really hoping I can make something work in SQL Server for this project.

I think this can be done using a loop in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Looping is generally not the way you solve any problems in SQL - SQL is designed and optimized to work with sets, not one row at a time.

Consider this source table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.src(DAY_ID int, Value int, Inserts int);

INSERT dbo.src VALUES
(5, 8,  2),
(4, 3,  0),
(3, 3,  0),
(2, 4,  1),
(1, 8,  0);
```

There are many ways to "explode" a set based on a single value. One is to split a set of commas (replicated to the length of the value, less 1).

```
-- INSERT dbo.src(DAY_ID, Value, Inserts)
SELECT 
  DAY_ID = DAY_ID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DAY_ID ORDER BY @@SPID),
  src.Value, 
  Inserts = 0
FROM dbo.src
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',', src.Inserts-1), ',') AS v
WHERE src.Inserts > 0;
```

Output:

| DAY_ID | Value | Inserts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | 8 | 0 |

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7V2VI0G0).

Comment: This works great thank you, is it possible to do without string_split() function? As I have some databases that don't have access to that function